# Why am I asked for a credit card number to download a free app?

Tags: itunes, iphone, ios-appstore

I  want to download free app in my iPod touch device and i have the following doubts.

Kindly resolve me doubts.

1. when i try to download it asks my credit card security number.
2. since i am trying to download free app , why do i need to provide my credit card security code?
3. Will i be debited for downloading the free app from app store?

I cant able to find any information regarding this on apple.

Please provide me some references about this from apple and please resolve my doubts.

Thanks a lot.