# Skype installation on ipad

Tags: install, skype, touch-id

I recently bought an ipad with ios 16.6.  When I tried to install Skype, it refused to do it without a Touch ID.  When I put my finger to the button, it wrote something like payment is authorised.  Does it mean that Micro$oft took money for installing Skype?  Or that it will take money for using Skype whenever it wants to?

PS: I am supposed to edit my question to explain how does the question ["Why do I need a credit card when I am downloading a free app from the app store on a iPad mini"](https://Does%20this%20answer%20your%20question?%20Why%20do%20I%20need%20a%20credit%20card%20when%20I%20am%20downloading%20a%20free%20app%20from%20the%20app%20store%20on%20a%20iPad%20mini?) is different from mine.

1. Fingerprint and credit card are two different things, so I don't understand why should it answer my question.  Credit card is an object. Fingerpint is not an object.
2. That question was asked 9 years 10 months ago.
3. The main answer starts with "I don't know of any way to set up an existing Apple ID for use with the App Store without supplying a credit card (or other payment source) (unless it's an iCloud account, I think -- it's not completely consistent)."  Does it mean (I am just trying to make sense of the "Your question has been identified as a possible duplicate of another question") that now you need a fingerprint to set up an existing ID for use with the App Store?  Why?

Comment: Can you add the store link of the Skype app you installed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need a credit card when I am downloading a free app from the app store on a iPad mini?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107988/why-do-i-need-a-credit-card-when-i-am-downloading-a-free-app-from-the-app-store)

Comment: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/skype/id304878510

Comment: @Allan Not really.  The answer is "I don't know of any way to set up an existing Apple ID for use with the App Store without supplying a credit card (or other payment source) (unless it's an iCloud account, I think -- it's not completely consistent)."  Do you mean that I need a fingerprint to set up an Apple ID?  Why?  Why does Skype need Apple ID?

Comment: TouchID is used in place of username/password for [authenticating and making purchases](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201371). Free apps (like Skype) require purchasing as paid ones do.  None of that allows an app  for recurring or surprise charges unless you authorize it.

Answer (score 2):

Any initial installation from the app store needs to be authorized by the user, doesn't matter if you are installing a free or a paid app.

If you don't want to use TouchID but rather enter your store password each time, you can do this in Settings -> Touch ID & Code.